# How to get the legend for for these codes in ggplot 2 , R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to get the legend for these codes using ggplot2, but I struggle to do it

Here are my codes

```html
qote<- function(x,a) { 
    z<- (x^3+a)-10
    return(z)}
m1 <- c(0.5, -.5)
n2 <- c("blue","red")[seq_along(m1)]
gg<- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(-2, 2)), aes(x))+
    theme(legend.position = c(-1,-0.9))
for (i in seq_along(m1)){  
    gg <- gg+ stat_function(fun = qote, color=n2[i], args=list(a=m1[i]))   
}
gg
```

I want to get legend  for these two curves in the inside of the plot (top left):
the curve blue= Time1;  The curve red= Time 2. I want to keep the codes, a simple code using ggplot2 would be very good if at all possible. Please also consider I may increase the curves until 7.

Comment: I do not think this question deserves a negative vote. Happy to update  it if you advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting `aes(color)` and then adding a `scale_color_manual`:

```r
ggplot(tibble(x = c(-2, 2)), aes(x)) +
  map(1:length(m1), 
      ~stat_function(fun = qote, aes(color = paste0("Time ", .)), args=list(a=m1[.]))) +
  scale_color_manual("curve legend", values = n2)
```

*Fine to use a for loop too, I just found it easier to write out with `map`.

**Edit** Per OP comments
For-loop version, with changed legends:

```r
qote<- function(x,a) { 
  z<- (x^3+a)-10
  return(z)}
m1 <- c(0.5, -.5)
n2 <- c("blue","red")

gg <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-2, 2)), aes(x)) 

for (i in seq_along(m1)) {
  gg <- gg + 
    stat_function(fun = qote, aes_(color = paste0("Time ", i)), args=list(a = m1[i]))
} 

gg + scale_color_manual("curve legend", values = n2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, How we could increase the number of curves?

Comment: This solution will scale arbitrarily with the number of elements defined in `m1` (and, by association, `x` and `n2`).

Comment: I am sorry, it does not work for me at all, Can I keep my codes

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you saying that if you run this code, it does not produce the graph shown?  What do you mean "keep my codes"?  Happy to make updates, just let me know what isn't working.

Comment: If you see my question, I said " I want to keep the codes, a simple code using ggplot2 would be very good if at all possible. Please also consider I may increase the curves until 7."

Comment: Would you be able to correct legend as I mentioned in my question?

Comment: The `map` function is the same thing as your iteration, just a simpler way to represent it.  See update for your for loop approach.